# How can I generate an impulse-like response to a centered wave crossing upward past 0V?

Tags: vco

I am a newbie audio electronics hobbyist. Some collaborator friends and I were thinking about a useful control voltage application, and thought that a spiky 'impulse-like' response to an input voltage crossing the zero line upward (see graph below illustrating our idea: an input waveform in black increases past the zero line, and an impulse-like spiky wave in magenta is the result).

[image: Impulse-like spiky wave in response to an input wave going into positive voltage.]

The spiky response would not be an idealized impulse, of course, and we expect both that there might be a slight delay in the response compared to where the voltage truly increased past 0V, and that the duration of an actual spike might vary with the frequency of the input waveform (or not?). We are a bit stumped about how to create this, though.

If we amplified the input waveform to saturation, we would create a pulse-width encoding of it. And if we could generate a spiky response to the input crossing 0V in the same direction, we think a diode could limit us to just the positive spikes. But how could we generate the spikes in the first place? Would subtracting a slightly delayed copy of a pulse width signal be the way to go?

Answers steering towards useful principles for newbie hobbyists welcome. :)

Comment: Welcome! How long does the impulse need to be? Is the frequency of the signal somewhat constrained? Would a tight window comparator do the job?

Comment: Thank you, @winny! I am unsure about duration of the impulse… conferring with my collaborator and will check back. We are in the audio domain so impulse ideally solution would be responsive to roughly frequencies of 20Hz–20kHz. I do not know if a window comparator would work! For example, might that produce spikes just before the input waveform *decreases* below zero? What do you think?

Comment: Must read: https://sound-au.com/appnotes/an005.htm

Comment: That is really lovely, @winny, thank you! None of the applications seem to distinguish between increasing above zero and decreasing below zero, though. So that wold give us twice the frequency we are looking for. Ideas?

Comment: I could dream up some logic to differentiate between them for you, but you need to ask yourself in 2023 if it’s worth it compared to the cheapest MCU with ADC built in and just do it in code instead. How close to the actual zero crossing do you need it to be? Could you accept jitter or delay? Hysteresis for small amplitudes?

Answer (score 2):

> if we could generate a spiky response to the input crossing 0V in the same direction, we think a diode could limit us to just the positive spikes. But how could we generate the spikes in the first place?

You can use a [differentiator circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiator).

For example:

[image: Public domain image from Wikimedia]

Comment: Would a differentiator circuit produce a burst, or something more like a square wave from, say, a triangle wave input?

Comment: With a triangle wave input it will produce a square wave output. But you are putting it after your saturated amplifier, which produces square waves, so the differentiator will produce narrow pulses.

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is looking like our solution as (implemented in the falstad.com simulator). The comparator produces a pulse-width encoding of the input wave form, and the CR high pass filter turns that into a spike, the diode with the second CR filter leaves us just with the positive voltage spike.

[image: A simple increasing past zero detector for audio applications]

We get pretty good approximation of our desired behavior in the simulation from 20Hz to 5kHz-ish (at the higher frequencies, the spike's duration starts looking like the width of the input wave, which does not work for us, and we are tinkering about with solutions which will get us to 20k-ish… precise C & R values, further op-amp tricks…). We have not yet moved to breadboard, but this seems a likely route.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the width of the 'spike' to be controlled you could 'AND' a differentiator + comparator output with a zero-crossing detector (basically a window comparator centered around 0V)

The differentiator would detect the positive-going portion of the wave (so there would be a minimum dv/dt to reliably drive the output high).

The zero crossing detector would be high for the time the voltage is very close to 0V.

So the width of the pulse would vary depending on the time the input waveform was within the window.

[image]